# Modify Breadcrumbs JavaScript to pull from H1 Tags instead of the URL? Desperate!

Tags: javascript

So the structure of this website I've been told to work on is awful, the url turns into a long line after you go into one section of the website (it's using an external program to import information, so it gets wonky)

`function breadcrumbs() {
  sURL = new String;
  bits = new Object;
  var x = 0;
  var stop = 0;
  var output = "home » ";`

`sURL = location.href;
  sURL = sURL.slice(8,sURL.length);
  chunkStart = sURL.indexOf("/");
  sURL = sURL.slice(chunkStart+1,sURL.length)`

`while(!stop){
    chunkStart = sURL.indexOf("/");
    if (chunkStart != -1){
      bits[x] = sURL.slice(0,chunkStart)
      sURL = sURL.slice(chunkStart+1,sURL.length);
    } else {
      stop = 1;
    }
    x++;
  }`

`for(var i in bits){
    output += "" + bits[i] + " » ";
  }
  document.write(output + document.title);
  document.write("");
  }`

Using this script I was able to get the breadcrumbs navigation to work however it pulls from the URL, can this be modified to pull from the H1 tags of the current page?

SO appreciated if anyone can help!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Javascript

Comment: This is a Javascript question, not an ExpressionEngine one. It might be better asked on StackOverflow instead of the ExpressionEngine StackExchange site.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementByTagName('h1');
```

This will get the  tag but I can't see how you would build a breadcrumb trail from a single heading. You should ask this on StackOverflow.

Comment: Home - <h1></h1> - <h1></h1> 

So it would look like that, basically, with the script I pasted above it is working however what it DISPLAYS as text in the breadcrumbs it is getting from the URL, I want this to instead get the title from the h1 of the current page it is on. Hopefully makes more sense.

As for your answer, do I just edit:

   document.write(output + document.title);

Comment: It doesn't make sense I'm afraid. A breadcrumb trail shows the path to the current page right? The URL also does that. The page title (or h1 tag) doesn't do that as a rule - it simply shows the current page. Ergo, you can't build a complete breadcrumb trail from the title alone. You really need to ask this question in an appropriate forum.